# How to retrieve all text files from multiple different directories?

Tags: php, glob

You may have heard of the `glob` method but that only manages to retrieve files from the directory that the file containing the method is located on - only one directory.

This is an example of the code that I am using:

```
<?php

foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) 
{
    $time = filemtime($filename);
    $files[$time] = $filename;
}

krsort($files);

foreach ($files as $file) {
echo $file;

}

?>
```

What happens here is that all of the **text files** in the current directory are retrieved, they are then sorted by order of **date modified** and are then echoed out onto the page.

The problem with this is that I don't just want to retrieve text files from the **one** directory.

How would I change this so that I can retrieve files from **multiple** directories of my choice all from one page - so I can echo out all of the text files from the multiple directories onto one page rather than only echoing out the text files from **one** directory?

I believe I would need to store all the directories I want to *glob* into an array but I am not sure how to retrieve it.

Comment: you should probably use the [recursive directory iterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example stolen from the page in my comment above

```
<?php

$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/project/');
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
$Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+\.txt$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

?>
```